# custom pipeline on time of browsing a page

Tags: sitecore

I want to call a LayoutResolver custom pipeline on time of browsing a page.
For that i created a custom pipeline and configured as below

```
<httpRequestBegin>
  <processor patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.LayoutResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']" 
             type="Agents.Common.PipeLines.LayoutResolver, Agents.Common" />      
</httpRequestBegin>
```

But its not working on time of browsing a page but its working when i am clicking any even from sitecore .

How it will work on time of browsing a page.

Comment: 1) Check you sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx file to determine processors order
2) There can be args.AbortPipeline() in some of previous processors that skip following processors

Answer (score 1):

Based on the patch syntax you provided, it looks like you have configured your LayoutResolver to run after the existing LayoutResolver.

Were you intending instead to replace the existing resolver? Or to run your logic before it?

For replacing, you will want to use `patch:instead`. For running before the existing resolver, you will want to use `patch:before`

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of how your processor is configured, the HTTP request begin pipeline executes for most if not all Sitecore requests - even shell ones, which I think is what you refer to in your question.

The easiest thing to start off with would be to verify that the context site is `website` (or whichever Sitecore site you want to affect) and anything else that might distinguish requests you want (e.g. page mode).